# Power BI Service refreshing a dataset error

Tags: powerbi, dataset, report, scheduling, business-intelligence

[image: a snapshot of an error]

Here is the issue I'm facing. It successfully refreshes the data in Power BI desktop, however, when I publish it I get this error. Didn't change any data sources or anything, just refreshed the data, that's it. Tried all the solutions mentioned in this post --> [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/publishing-is-complete-however-we-couldn-t-refresh-your-dataset/m-p/745636)

Nothing worked. Would appreciate any help as it's effecting an important report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create power bi gateway successfully on server ?

Comment: Yes,I double-checked it, and it works fine

Comment: try to delete dataset and republish it, As I remember it worked for me, or you can rename and publish again. I know its silly method, but it worked .

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the only option left. Thanks for your help, I'll try republishing it

Comment: How is progress